# Use Nvidia in an Intel/Nvidia hybrid setup running Manjaro Linux

Tags: nvidia, graphics, manjaro

I am running the latest version of Manjaro and I have noticed that I am not using my Nvidia graphics card.

These are my installed drivers:

```
$ mhwd -l -d
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> PCI Device: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.4/0000:02:00.0 (0200:10ec:8168)
  Network controller Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  > INSTALLED:

   NAME:    network-r8168
   ATTACHED:    PCI
   VERSION: 2016.04.20
   INFO:    RealTek RTL-8168 Gigabit Ethernet driver
   PRIORITY:    0
   FREEDRIVER:  true
   DEPENDS: -
   CONFLICTS:   -
   CLASSIDS:    0200 
   VENDORIDS:   1186 10ec 



  > AVAILABLE:

   NAME:    network-r8168
   ATTACHED:    PCI
   VERSION: 2016.04.20
   INFO:    RealTek RTL-8168 Gigabit Ethernet driver
   PRIORITY:    0
   FREEDRIVER:  true
   DEPENDS: -
   CONFLICTS:   -
   CLASSIDS:    0200 
   VENDORIDS:   1186 10ec 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> PCI Device: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0 (0302:10de:134d)
  Display controller nVidia Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  > INSTALLED:

   NAME:    video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-430xx-bumblebee
   ATTACHED:    PCI
   VERSION: 2019.08.24
   INFO:    Hybrid bumblebee solution for NVIDIA Optimus Technology - Closed source NVIDIA driver & open source intel driver.
   PRIORITY:    10
   FREEDRIVER:  false
   DEPENDS: -
   CONFLICTS:   video-intel video-nvidia-435xx video-nvidia-430xx video-nvidia-418xx video-nvidia-390xx video-nvidia-340xx video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-418xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-390xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-340xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nouveau-bumblebee 
   CLASSIDS:    0300 0302 0300 
   VENDORIDS:   10de 8086 

   NAME:    video-linux
   ATTACHED:    PCI
   VERSION: 2018.05.04
   INFO:    Standard open source drivers.
   PRIORITY:    2
   FREEDRIVER:  true
   DEPENDS: -
   CONFLICTS:   -
   CLASSIDS:    0300 0380 0302 
   VENDORIDS:   1002 8086 10de 



  > AVAILABLE:

   NAME:    video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-430xx-bumblebee
   ATTACHED:    PCI
   VERSION: 2019.08.24
   INFO:    Hybrid bumblebee solution for NVIDIA Optimus Technology - Closed source NVIDIA driver & open source intel driver.
   PRIORITY:    10
   FREEDRIVER:  false
   DEPENDS: -
   CONFLICTS:   video-intel video-nvidia-435xx video-nvidia-430xx video-nvidia-418xx video-nvidia-390xx video-nvidia-340xx video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-418xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-390xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-340xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nouveau-bumblebee 
   CLASSIDS:    0300 0302 0300 
   VENDORIDS:   10de 8086 

   NAME:    video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-418xx-bumblebee
   ATTACHED:    PCI
   VERSION: 2019.08.24
   INFO:    Hybrid bumblebee solution for NVIDIA Optimus Technology - Closed source NVIDIA driver & open source intel driver.
   PRIORITY:    9
   FREEDRIVER:  false
   DEPENDS: -
   CONFLICTS:   video-intel video-nvidia-435xx video-nvidia-430xx video-nvidia-418xx video-nvidia-390xx video-nvidia-340xx video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-430xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-390xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-340xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nouveau-bumblebee 
   CLASSIDS:    0300 0302 0300 
   VENDORIDS:   10de 8086 

   NAME:    video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-390xx-bumblebee
   ATTACHED:    PCI
   VERSION: 2019.08.23
   INFO:    Hybrid bumblebee solution for NVIDIA Optimus Technology - Closed source NVIDIA driver & open source intel driver.
   PRIORITY:    8
   FREEDRIVER:  false
   DEPENDS: -
   CONFLICTS:   video-intel video-nvidia-435xx video-nvidia-430xx video-nvidia-418xx video-nvidia-390xx video-nvidia-340xx video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-430xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-418xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-340xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nouveau-bumblebee 
   CLASSIDS:    0300 0302 0300 
   VENDORIDS:   10de 8086 

   NAME:    video-nvidia-435xx
   ATTACHED:    PCI
   VERSION: 2019.08.25
   INFO:    Closed source NVIDIA drivers for linux.
   PRIORITY:    7
   FREEDRIVER:  false
   DEPENDS: -
   CONFLICTS:   video-intel video-nvidia-430xx video-nvidia-418xx video-nvidia-390xx video-nvidia-340xx video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-430xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-418xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-390xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-340xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nouveau-bumblebee 
   CLASSIDS:    0300 0302 
   VENDORIDS:   10de 

   NAME:    video-nvidia-430xx
   ATTACHED:    PCI
   VERSION: 2019.08.25
   INFO:    Closed source NVIDIA drivers for linux.
   PRIORITY:    6
   FREEDRIVER:  false
   DEPENDS: -
   CONFLICTS:   video-intel video-nvidia-435xx video-nvidia-418xx video-nvidia-390xx video-nvidia-340xx video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-430xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-418xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-390xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-340xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nouveau-bumblebee 
   CLASSIDS:    0300 0302 
   VENDORIDS:   10de 

   NAME:    video-nvidia-418xx
   ATTACHED:    PCI
   VERSION: 2019.08.24
   INFO:    Closed source NVIDIA drivers for linux.
   PRIORITY:    5
   FREEDRIVER:  false
   DEPENDS: -
   CONFLICTS:   video-intel video-nvidia-435xx video-nvidia-430xx video-nvidia-390xx video-nvidia-340xx video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-435xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-430xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-390xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-340xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nouveau-bumblebee 
   CLASSIDS:    0300 0302 
   VENDORIDS:   10de 

   NAME:    video-nvidia-390xx
   ATTACHED:    PCI
   VERSION: 2019.08.23
   INFO:    Closed source NVIDIA drivers for linux.
   PRIORITY:    4
   FREEDRIVER:  false
   DEPENDS: -
   CONFLICTS:   video-intel video-nvidia-435xx video-nvidia-430xx video-nvidia-418xx video-nvidia-340xx video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-430xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-418xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-390xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nouveau-bumblebee 
   CLASSIDS:    0300 0302 
   VENDORIDS:   10de 

   NAME:    video-linux
   ATTACHED:    PCI
   VERSION: 2018.05.04
   INFO:    Standard open source drivers.
   PRIORITY:    2
   FREEDRIVER:  true
   DEPENDS: -
   CONFLICTS:   -
   CLASSIDS:    0300 0380 0302 
   VENDORIDS:   1002 8086 10de 


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> PCI Device: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0 (0300:8086:1916)
  Display controller Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  > INSTALLED:

   NAME:    video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-430xx-bumblebee
   ATTACHED:    PCI
   VERSION: 2019.08.24
   INFO:    Hybrid bumblebee solution for NVIDIA Optimus Technology - Closed source NVIDIA driver & open source intel driver.
   PRIORITY:    10
   FREEDRIVER:  false
   DEPENDS: -
   CONFLICTS:   video-intel video-nvidia-435xx video-nvidia-430xx video-nvidia-418xx video-nvidia-390xx video-nvidia-340xx video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-418xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-390xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-340xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nouveau-bumblebee 
   CLASSIDS:    0300 0302 0300 
   VENDORIDS:   10de 8086 

   NAME:    video-linux
   ATTACHED:    PCI
   VERSION: 2018.05.04
   INFO:    Standard open source drivers.
   PRIORITY:    2
   FREEDRIVER:  true
   DEPENDS: -
   CONFLICTS:   -
   CLASSIDS:    0300 0380 0302 
   VENDORIDS:   1002 8086 10de 



  > AVAILABLE:

   NAME:    video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-430xx-bumblebee
   ATTACHED:    PCI
   VERSION: 2019.08.24
   INFO:    Hybrid bumblebee solution for NVIDIA Optimus Technology - Closed source NVIDIA driver & open source intel driver.
   PRIORITY:    10
   FREEDRIVER:  false
   DEPENDS: -
   CONFLICTS:   video-intel video-nvidia-435xx video-nvidia-430xx video-nvidia-418xx video-nvidia-390xx video-nvidia-340xx video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-418xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-390xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-340xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nouveau-bumblebee 
   CLASSIDS:    0300 0302 0300 
   VENDORIDS:   10de 8086 

   NAME:    video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-418xx-bumblebee
   ATTACHED:    PCI
   VERSION: 2019.08.24
   INFO:    Hybrid bumblebee solution for NVIDIA Optimus Technology - Closed source NVIDIA driver & open source intel driver.
   PRIORITY:    9
   FREEDRIVER:  false
   DEPENDS: -
   CONFLICTS:   video-intel video-nvidia-435xx video-nvidia-430xx video-nvidia-418xx video-nvidia-390xx video-nvidia-340xx video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-430xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-390xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-340xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nouveau-bumblebee 
   CLASSIDS:    0300 0302 0300 
   VENDORIDS:   10de 8086 

   NAME:    video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-390xx-bumblebee
   ATTACHED:    PCI
   VERSION: 2019.08.23
   INFO:    Hybrid bumblebee solution for NVIDIA Optimus Technology - Closed source NVIDIA driver & open source intel driver.
   PRIORITY:    8
   FREEDRIVER:  false
   DEPENDS: -
   CONFLICTS:   video-intel video-nvidia-435xx video-nvidia-430xx video-nvidia-418xx video-nvidia-390xx video-nvidia-340xx video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-430xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-418xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nvidia-340xx-bumblebee video-hybrid-intel-nouveau-bumblebee 
   CLASSIDS:    0300 0302 0300 
   VENDORIDS:   10de 8086 

   NAME:    video-linux
   ATTACHED:    PCI
   VERSION: 2018.05.04
   INFO:    Standard open source drivers.
   PRIORITY:    2
   FREEDRIVER:  true
   DEPENDS: -
   CONFLICTS:   -
   CLASSIDS:    0300 0380 0302 
   VENDORIDS:   1002 8086 10de 

   NAME:    video-vesa
   ATTACHED:    PCI
   VERSION: 2017.03.12
   INFO:    X.org vesa video driver.
   PRIORITY:    0
   FREEDRIVER:  true
   DEPENDS: -
   CONFLICTS:   -
   CLASSIDS:    0300 
   VENDORIDS:   *
```

But when I test to see what GPU is currently used I get the following

```
$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.1.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.1.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 19.1.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

How do I properly configure my system so it uses my Nvidia graphics card, and so as to be able to switch between the two?

Comment: Use Nvidia X Server Settings.